# remove rows from pandas data frame with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame...in one of its columns, there is list of strings. I want to define a condition for it. This condition is that if a list in each row has the length less than 2 strings, drop whole row from data frame and make a new one.
I use to write this code for it . but it doesn't work!

```
new_dataframe = dataframe.drop(x for x in dataframe['specific column'][:] if x in len(dataframe['specific column'][:])<2)
```

[:] is there to consider all rows of this specific column

and I receive this error:

```
'labels [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fcc19dd80a0>] not contained in axis'
```

Comment: Having a sample of the dataset your interested in working with would increase your changes of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
# Test dataframe with lists of strings
df = pd.DataFrame({"specific column": [
    ["a", "b"],
    ["a", "b", "c",],
    ["a",],
    ["a", "b", "c", "d"]], })

# Select indices of rows with less than 2 items in list
ix = df["specific column"].str.len() < 2

# Select all other rows
df.loc[~ix]
```

Comment: I received this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: becasue in rach row of each column, I have a list of strings

Comment: @CFD then the thing referenced by the name `dataframe` is **not** a dataframe and you should figure that out.

Comment: @koPytok you should use `dataframe['specific_column'].str.len()`